# Delay doesn't work in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, button

hello i am trying to make an effect with the help of jquery but i want to delay the blur effect after click but it doesn't workHere is my pen: http://www.codepen.io/asder/pen/rLmVRp

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".wavy").click(function() {
        $(".wavy").delay(1200).blur()
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout function for this:

```
$(".wavy").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".wavy").blur()
  },1200);
});
```